# How can I change an html based on which link the user clicks?

Tags: python, sql, flask

I've created a database of recipes and on a recipes.html I display all the recipes and made the names links that I want to bring you to a new page that displays all of that recipes information. How can I make another html page for the single recipe that will change depending on which recipe a user chooses? I don't want to hard code a lot of html pages especially because a user could add a recipe to the data base. I'm working with Flask.

The table I have on recipes.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Recipe Title</th>
      <th>Total Time</th>
      <th>Difficulty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in names %}
      <tr>
          <td><a href="single-recipe.html">{{row[0]}}</a></td>
          <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use href with parameters and pass in an argument, such as `single-recipe?id=apple_pie`.

Then in flask you can get the id by doing

```py
@app.route(...)
def single-recipe():
    id = request.args.get('id')
```

And return the relevant page